# How to keep the selected column for sorting?

Tags: javascript

There is a gridview with the ability to sort by each column. If you sort an arbitrary column, and then select different filters for the selection and click submit button, the sorting on the selected column is reset. I want the selected column to retain the specified sort when applying filters.

At the moment I made a binding to the column, but when I click submit button, it's A-Z, then Z-A sorting. How do I save a custom selection?

```
sortHref = document.querySelector('#my-grid table thead tr .asc') || document.querySelector('#my-grid table thead tr .desc');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep sorting state between requests. This can be achieved in different ways:

1. Pass sorting params with your data when doing submits (via url or in post body's hidden field)
2. Store sorting state in a cookie.
3. Use browsers localstorage.